# Why do I need MEX?

Tags: wcf, mex

I understand that Metadata Exchange Endpoint helps the client to interact with the server properly. However I don't understand the difference between using it and not using it client wise. I mean, it is possible to establish client-server connection without MEX so what's the difference if I decide not to use it?

Answer (score 0):

The Metadata Exchange Endpoint (MEX) is an endpoint in WCF that exposes metadata used to describe the service. Without it, you will not be able to automatically generate a proxy class (using svcutil). In many cases it can be disabled on production environment. See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731823.aspx) for comprehensive explanation.

Comment: BTW. MEX is not the only way to expose metadata for svcutil to generate proxy classes. WSDL is a separate format that WCF can expose metadata via, however it is more limited (not all endpoints are supported).